# Javascript: How to access object on button click?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand how to create and update objects in response to a user clicking a button. I'm using cytoscape.js as part of this exercise, where after creating a graph on page load, clicking a button updates a box on the page with the count of the nodes. Retrieving the graph object cy with document.getElementById('cy') returns *something* but subsequently trying to access the nodes fails, as the object methods (such as .elements() or .nodes() ) are undefined. Clearly the object I'm getting back with .getElementById('cy') isn't the graph object.

So my question is, how do I access the graph object?

```js
function count_nodes() {
    var node_count = 0;
    var cy = document.getElementById('cy');
    console.log(cy)
    console.log(cy.elements("[foo>1]"));
  
    document.getElementById('out').value = node_count;
  
}

$(function(){ // on dom ready

var elesJson = {
  nodes: [
    { data: { id: 'a', foo: 3, bar: 5, baz: 7 } },
    { data: { id: 'b', foo: 7, bar: 1, baz: 3 } },
    { data: { id: 'c', foo: 2, bar: 7, baz: 6 } },
    { data: { id: 'd', foo: 9, bar: 5, baz: 2 } },
    { data: { id: 'e', foo: 2, bar: 4, baz: 5 } }
  ], 

  edges: [{ data: { id: 'ae', weight: 1, source: 'a', target: 'e' } },
    { data: { id: 'ab', weight: 3, source: 'a', target: 'b' } },
    { data: { id: 'be', weight: 4, source: 'b', target: 'e' } },
    { data: { id: 'bc', weight: 5, source: 'b', target: 'c' } },
    { data: { id: 'ce', weight: 6, source: 'c', target: 'e' } },
    { data: { id: 'cd', weight: 2, source: 'c', target: 'd' } },
    { data: { id: 'de', weight: 7, source: 'd', target: 'e' } }
    
  ]
};
  
$('#cy').cytoscape({
  style: cytoscape.stylesheet()
    .selector('node')
      .css({
        'background-color': '#B3767E',
        'width': 'mapData(baz, 0, 10, 10, 40)',
        'height': 'mapData(baz, 0, 10, 10, 40)',
        'content': 'data(id)'
      })
    .selector('edge')
      .css({
        'line-color': '#F2B1BA',
        'target-arrow-color': '#F2B1BA',
        'width': 2,
        'target-arrow-shape': 'circle',
        'opacity': 0.8
      })
    .selector(':selected')
      .css({
        'background-color': 'black',
        'line-color': 'black',
        'target-arrow-color': 'black',
        'source-arrow-color': 'black',
        'opacity': 1
      })
    .selector('.faded')
      .css({
        'opacity': 0.25,
        'text-opacity': 0
      }),
  
  elements: elesJson,
  
  layout: {
    name: 'circle',
    padding: 10
  },
  
  ready: function(){
    // ready 1
  }
});
  
  }); // on dom ready
```

```html
 <div class="box">    
        <label for="out"><abbr title="Quantity">Num Nodes</abbr></label>
        <input id="out" value="0" />
      <button id="count" onclick="count_nodes()">Count</button>
    </div>
```

(My apologies for what is probably a basic question, I'm very new to JS)

Comment: [HTMLElement (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement) I don't see a method `elements()` there.

Comment: Ok, so how do I access the graph object (cy) on the button click?

Comment: To clarify, it's the cytoscape object `cy` that has the method `elements()`, my problem is how to access that object after the button is clicked.

Comment: Yep, it's basic JavaScript. Notice that every event-handler is given an `event` parameter, and a way to get `this`.  Also read-up on the variable scoping rules: a `var` that is declared inside of a function is visible only within that function and disappears when it is gone. But JavaScript, as a language, basically does not *have* a "compile time." Syntactic and semantic errors which other compilers would detect ... JS won't.  (Which is one of the big reasons why "transpilers," which *generate* JS from source-code that is in a "stronger" language, have become so popular.)